# Are these groups isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

1) $(\Bbb Z,+)$ and the subgroup of $(\Bbb Q-\{0\}, *)$ generated by $3/5$

2) $\langle\{(ac)(de),(abcde)\}\rangle$ and $D_{10}$(Dihedral Group of order $10$)

1)My intuition tells me that $(\Bbb Z,+)$ and the subgroup of $(\Bbb Q - \{0\}, *)$ generated by $3/5$ is not isomorphic. But Why?

2)The order of the groups is 10, but do their elements have the same order?

I am not sure what are the elements of <{(ac)(de),(abcde)}> is that {(ac)(de), (abcde), (aedcd).... What else?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

== What can you say of the map

$$f:\Bbb Z\to \left\langle\;\frac35\;\right\rangle\;,\;\;f(n):=\left(\frac{3}5\right)^n\;?$$

== There are only two groups of order ten up to isomorphism, only one of which is abelian (cyclic, BTW).

Comment: The map $f$ should really be $n\to\left(\frac35\right)^n$.

Comment: Of course, @SteveD. Thanks.

Comment: Z is isomorphic to <3/4>. And what is BTW?

Comment: BTW = By the way.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a cyclic group of infinite order. What can you say about the other group?

2) The dihedral groups has some relations. $r^5=s^2=e$ and $rs=sr^{-1}$. Check whether or not the elements you have in $S_5$ (Im assuming) satisfy this relations.